# Datetime class unexpected date output

Tags: python

```
time_str = "8:00"
time_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(time_str,"%H:%M")
print(time_dt)
```

why is the output giving '1900-01-01 08:00:00' when no date was mentioned??

I tried in different notebooks, still getting the same answer.

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: Maybe you want `time.strptime` rather than `datetime.strptime`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `.strptime` method without providing a date it will use its default value which is '1900-01-01' in python.
If you want only the time part, you can use the `.time` method.

```
time_str = "8:00"
time_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M").time()
print(time_dt)
```